# Auto-detect Typescript version based on folder for VS Code multi-root workspace

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code

**The problem:**

I am working on a multi-root workspace that has two packages under multi-root folders with different Typescript versions. VS Code doesn't seem to be smart enough to automatically switch Typescript versions when editing a file under one package and then switching to edit a file under the other package.

**What I want:**

Ideally it would behave like the `typescript.tsdk` workspace setting and automatically detect the correct Typescript version depending on which multi-root folder you are currently in.